# estrutura errada no meu código! não cai em nenhuma condição

Tags: python, formatação

Preciso fazer um programa em python usando o WHILE e IF para descobrir se um numero digitado é primo ou não.

Abaixo segue meu código.
Não consigo encontrar onde esta meu erro, pois se digito qualquer valor acima de 2 não cai nas condições que eu tratei.

Sei que é um erro de iniciante, acho q o erro esta nas colocações das linhas de dentro das estruturas. No código estou tratando as divisões do numero digitado do 1 ate ele mesmo. Não estou sabendo formatar meu código aqui no site por isso vou postar ele em texto e em imagem.

```py
Numero = int(input("Digite um numero inteiro: "))
if Numero == 2:
        print("Seu numero 2 é primo")
ContadorDeDivisores = 0
Divisor = 1
cont = 0
if Numero > 2:
    while cont < Numero:
            if Numero % Divisor == 0:
                ContadorDeDivisores = ContadorDeDivisores + 1
                Divisor = Divisor + 1
                cont = cont + 1
    if ContadorDeDivisores > 2:
        print("Seu numero",Numero,"não é primo")
    else:
        print("Seu numero",Numero,"é primo")

while Numero == 0 or Numero == 1:
    print("O numero que você quer verificar se é primo tem que ser maior ou igual a 2")
    Numero = int(input("Digite novamente um numero inteiro: "))
    if Numero == 2:
        print("Seu numero 2 é primo")
    if Numero > 2:
        while cont < Numero:
            if Numero % Divisor == 0:
                ContadorDeDivisores = ContadorDeDivisores + 1
                Divisor = Divisor + 1
                cont = cont + 1
        if ContadorDeDivisores > 2:
            print("Seu numero",Numero,"não é primo")
        else:
            print("Seu numero",Numero,"é primo")
```

[image: meu código]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem muitas coisas que podem ser melhoradas no seu código.
Como uma sugestão, você poderia fazer a verificação do input do usuário logo no início, e só partir e fazer o loop uma vez, dado que o input foi adequado. Dessa forma, você não precisa escrever esse while duas vezes, e nem os prints.

Outra sugestão é inicializar o "Divisor" com 2, desta forma você não precisaria verificar se o número de divisores é maior que dois. Se existir algum divisor além do 1 você já sabe que não é primo, podendo até interromper o fluxo antes.

Por último, não acredito que você necessite de uma variável "Cont". Toda a contagem necessária já é feita pela variável "Divisor".

Posto tudo isso de lado, o erro no seu código é que o incremento de "Divisor" e "Cont" deve ser feito fora do If. Isto é, com palavras, você deve tentar o próximo divisor independente do caso atual ter sido um divisor inteiro ou não, da seguinte forma:

```py
while Divisor < Numero:
            if Numero % Divisor == 0:
                ContadorDeDivisores = ContadorDeDivisores + 1
            Divisor = Divisor + 1
```

Existem uma última dica, mais matemática, que diz que você só precisa testar até Divisor ser maior do que a raiz quadrada do número pedido, mas acredito que isso não seja adequado para um programa com propósito didático. (Ou prevenir o usuário de digitar números negativos por exemplo).

Com essa modificação seu programa funciona corretamente:

```
Digite um numero inteiro: 5
Seu numero 5 é primo 
Digite um numero inteiro: 6
Seu numero 6 não é primo
```